# The CJS build of Vite's Node API is deprecated

Tags: vite

I get a warning when I run `vite build` (Vite 5)

```
The CJS build of Vite's Node API is deprecated. See https://vitejs.dev/guide/troubleshooting.html#vite-cjs-node-api-deprecated for more details.
```

On the [linked page](https://vitejs.dev/guide/troubleshooting.html#vite-cjs-node-api-deprecated) it says

> If you're unsure where the warning is coming from, you can run your script with the VITE_CJS_TRACE=true flag to log the stack trace:

But how do I do that? I tried adding that to my script like this     `"build": "VITE_CJS_TRACE=true vite build",`, but that gives me an error:

```
VITE_CJS_TRACE=true vite build
VITE_CJS_TRACE' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

Answer (score 7):

If you use `JS` then change the `vite.config.js` file name to `vite.config.mjs`

Similarly, if you use `TS` change the file name to `vite.config.mts` instead of `vite.config.ts`

### OR

Set `"type": "module"` on `package.json` file

For more details read the vite documentation from [here](https://vitejs.dev/guide/migration.html#deprecate-cjs-node-api)

Comment: Could you elaborate on this a bit, what's the _m_ for?

Comment: Yes, @Mangs you can read more about this from the documentation https://vitejs.dev/guide/migration.html#deprecate-cjs-node-api

Answer (score 3):

Solution was to use *set* along with the flag (at least to get it running in Powershell on Windows)

In `package.json`

```
"build": "set \"VITE_CJS_TRACE=true\" && vite build",
```

Comment: That's the ticket in Windows 

Answer (score 2):

For me (in Ubuntu), the anwser was to modify the build line in package.json as follows:

`"build": "VITE_CJS_TRACE=true vite build",`

This seems to be more in line with vite's doc pages:
https://vitejs.dev/guide/troubleshooting.html#vite-cjs-node-api-deprecated

Comment: Well, that didn't work on windows and that's part of the original question

Comment: Right, just mentioning this for ubuntu users, who, like me, end up here, trying to find a solution ;-)

Comment: I understand that, it was this part "more in line with vite's doc" that made me a bit confused ;)